# How to measure how much memory each gem requires at initialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, rubygems, bundler

I have a Rails 2.3.10 app with bundler. At startup the memory footprint is quite big (300MB in development mode).

I would like to see how much memory each gem takes on startup.

Comment: interesting approach, I fear you'd have to do this manually, unless there are [some hooks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events) in the gems. Beware of eager conclusions: `auto_load` could make results lame.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. New Relic reports over half a dynos memory being used on Heroku at startup. That's without anyone using the site...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We had a problem in which our basic Rails app, with no traffic or requests, had a footprint of ~140MB on startup.

We used the following approach to trace the memory requirement of each gem specified in the Gemfile of our app, without having to try to patch bundler.

1. using `rails new myappname` generate a new empty rails app
2. Copy the Gemfile from the main project to this new rails project
3. run `bundle install` and then `rails server` to ensure it is possible to boot up the rails server and that any basic configurations required are loaded
4. Open up the Gemfile and with the exception of the specification for the rails gem, append `require: false` at the end of each line. Ensure that any other gems that are specified with one name but required using :require => 'othergemname' are using the older ruby Hash notation so that the pattern match below will catch it.
5. Run `bundle install` again to regenerate the Gemfile.lock
6. Create the following script which will use manually require each gem specified in the Gemfile and log the system memory consumed by the rails process before and after.

   ```
   # require_and_profile.rb
   def require_and_profile(gemname = nil)
     unless gemname
       puts "%-20s: %10s | %10s" % ['gem','increment','total']
       return
     end
     # This is how to get memory of calling process in OS X, check host OS for variants
     memory_usage = `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i / 1024.0
     require gemname
     puts "%-20s: %10.2f | %10.2f" % [ gemname, (`ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i / 1024.0 - memory_usage), (`ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i / 1024.0)]
   end

   pattern = /^[^#]*gem[ ]*['"]([^,'"]*)['"][ ,~>0-9\.'"]*(:require[ => ]*['"]([^'"]*)['"][, ])?/

   require_and_profile
   File.open('Gemfile').each do |line|
     if line.match(pattern)
     if line.match(pattern)[3]
       require_and_profile line.match(pattern)[3]
     else
         require_and_profile line.match(pattern)[1]
       end
     end
   end
   ```
7. Run `rails c`
8. `load 'require_and_profile.rb'`
9. The output shows how much (in MB) each gem adds to the base app footprint (increment) and what the total footprint is after inclusion of the gem (total).

This helped us identify for example, that we'd been requiring asset-sync in our boot when we only needed it in the :asset group. We do find that on different boot-ups the memory footprint of each gem is not exactly the same, but running it a few times does show you the patterns of which ones are the memory-hungry gems.

Comment: This approach was really incredible helpful, I discovered that using optimal fog loading for ```carrierwave``` (https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#optimized-loading-of-fog) and an explicit ```:assets``` group reduced my memory footprint by 10 Mb.

Answer (score 16):

There is an easier way to do this now with the derailed gem:

add to your gemfile:

```
gem 'derailed', group: :development
```

then on the command line from your apps root:

```
bundle exec derailed bundle:mem
```

This will print out how much memory each gem takes as it's included.

Comment: It's now derailed_benchmarks [https://github.com/zombocom/derailed_benchmarks] instead. 

`gem 'derailed_benchmarks'`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

- Find the place within bundler where all the gems are required.
- after each gem is required, get the current object count (`c = 0; ObjectSpace.each_object { c += 1 }`)

This way you'll see which gem causes the most objects being instantiated and therefore indirectly causes most memory usage.

Two caveats though:

- memory usage is not really linear to number of objects, but you should get a good enough estimate about which gems are the worst offenders
- as already pointed out: gems might not load all their code when being required, so a gem might causes more memory usage later on when more code is loaded...